# Cant get Flask, Gunicorn and Nginx to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I've went through several tutorials, rebuilt my ubuntu image dozens of times and I still cant get this to work.

I'm trying to create an api using pythons flask framework. I can get it to work in develop mode (ie: http://555.555.555:5000), but in production it never seems to work. What am I doing wrong here?

I followed this particular tutorial ( [Deploying python application with nginx](https://medium.com/swlh/mini-project-deploying-python-application-with-nginx-30f9b25b195) ) and even though I can run the flask application using nginx, flask, or gunicorn separately, when I try to run it by requesting the url, all it returns is the "welcome to nginx" message.

I'm fairly close to scrapping python and returning to php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't added any code or screen shots because I followed the tutorial exactly as it was laid out. There was no deviation. Im assuming that there are steps left out of the process that a python expert would know of that I obviously would have missed.

Comment: That tutorial is missing a key step. You'll need to `sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`  before you restart the `nginx` service.

Comment: thnaks @DaveW.Smith I did as you suggested and now Im receiving a 502 error. I'm guessing that I need to reconfigure something or restart all services?

Comment: That may be a problem getting nginx to talk to gunicorn. Add your nginx config above.

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) on how to configure nginx to proxy for gunicorn.

Comment: in /etc/nginx/sites-available/py-app server 
{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to config your nginx.

Follow the `Step 5 — Configure Nginx` of your [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/mini-project-deploying-python-application-with-nginx-30f9b25b195).

Comment: That step fails to mention the need to remove the default configuration.

Comment: @Dave W. Smith There is no need to remove the default configuration to let the proxy working for your site as long as you set the right listening port and location for your localhost or static webpage, since it only renders when there is no additional settings overwrite. But as long as you solve this problem, it should be good solution.

Comment: Technically true "as long as ..." Or avoid problems by nuking the default config.

Comment: I followed this step and when I run sudo nginx -t I receive the syntax is ok and test is successful messages from nginx